# What is wrong here with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Already spent a lot of time with the sed and gsed, by just trying to match a stupid string, but it still doesn't work!

neither:

```
echo "123adv123" | sed -En 's/\([a-z]+\)/#/g'
```

nor:

```
echo "123adv123" | sed -En 's/([a-z]*)/#/g'
```

nor:

```
echo "123adv123" | sed -En 's/([a-z]+)/#/g'
```

nor:

```
echo "123adv123" | gsed -rn 's/\([a-z]+\)/#/g'
```

nor:

```
echo "123adv123" | gsed -rn 's/([a-z]+)/#/g'
```

I'm trying it on the OSX. I know the question looks really strange, but I stucked and just want to get the glue what is wrong here?

The output should be `123#123`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you provide expected output?

Comment: You aren't ever printing the pattern space. You'll never get any output from that. Drop the `n` argument. Alternatively, add `p` after the `g` to tell sed to print the line. Your last line works (with `s/gsed/sed/` and removing the `n` argument) here on CentOS linux with `GNU sed version 4.1.5`.

Comment: Remove the `-n` ("noprint") argument, or add a `p` ("print") to your `s` command: `s/a/b/gp`

Comment: thanks, and sorry for the stupid question, just stucked with it in a strange manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `-n` otherwise it will suppress output.

This works on OSX:

```
echo "123adv123" | sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\)/#/g'
```

So is this:

```
echo "123adv123" | gsed -r 's/([a-z]+)/#/g'
```

Or this:

```
echo "123adv123" | sed -E 's/([a-z]+)/#/g'
```

Or to print only substituted lines use:

```
sed -nE 's/([a-z]+)/#/pg' file
```

Comment: I thought it is to suppress unmatched lines. Ok, if I remove it, how will I suppress the lines without matching?

Comment: You can use: `sed -nE 's/([a-z]+)/#/pg' file`